# looping over lists of indexes within a function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I would like to create one loop over lists of indexes within a function. But I don't know exactly how I can do that.

The data I'm using:

```
data_ = {'Number_a': [12, 13, 14,15,16,17],'Number_b':[11,11,11,12,12,12],'Number_c': [10,5,4,3,2,1]}
data = pd.DataFrame(data=data_)
```

I have two functions which are called within one other function.
Definition of function 1 & 2:

```
def Multiplication_data(data,n):
    
    data["Number_a"]=data["Number_a"]*n
    
    return data

def Addition_data(data):
    
    data["Number_b"]=data["Number_b"]+data["Number_c"]
    
    return data
```

& this is the definition of the third function:

```
   def function_data(data,n):
   
        A1=Multiplication_data(data,n)
        A2=Addition_data(data)
  
    return A1,A2
```

I would like to create a loop within `function_data` , for each iteration I select different rows of `data` based on list of index `idx1, idx2 ...`
The way I imagined it to be:

```
 def function_data(data,n):
     idx1= [0,2,4]
     idx2=[1,3,5] 
     List=[idx1,idx2]
     for i in List:
         data=data.iloc[i]
         A1=Multiplication_data(data,n)
         A2=Addition_data(data)
     return A1,A2
```

I don't think this is the correct way to do it... Any ideas?

Comment: do you actually need the loop for this? why don't you combine lists into one `new_list=idx1+idx2` and select rows using it `df2 = data.iloc[new_list]`, later dance around the data with all the functions?

Comment: @NoobVB, this is a simplified example. Actually after the first iteration the dataframe with the idx1 indexes would pass in additional steps and functions.

Answer (score 0):

General Overview:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(data=data_)
n = 2

def function_data(df, n):
    data = df.copy()
    idx1= [0,2,4]
    idx2=[1,3,5] 
    ids = [idx1, idx2]
    for id in ids:
        print(data, '\n') # I print before each iteration just to show it's working.
        data.loc[id, 'Number_a'] = data.Number_a.mul(n)
        data.loc[id, 'Number_b'] = data.Number_b.add(data.Number_c)
    return data


data = function_data(data, n)
print(data, '\n')
```

Output:

```
   Number_a  Number_b  Number_c
0        12        11        10
1        13        11         5
2        14        11         4
3        15        12         3
4        16        12         2
5        17        12         1

   Number_a  Number_b  Number_c
0        24        21        10
1        13        11         5
2        28        15         4
3        15        12         3
4        32        14         2
5        17        12         1

   Number_a  Number_b  Number_c
0        24        21        10
1        26        16         5
2        28        15         4
3        30        15         3
4        32        14         2
5        34        13         1
```

Comment: Hi @BeRT2me, thank you for your answer. The example I gave is a very simplistic representation of my code. The functions I have in my code are very complicated and I cannot change them. I want to know only if there's a way to: in a loop  select specific rows from a data frame go through the functions and then for the next iteration select different rows based on the lists I have?

Comment: if I understood correctly, - you actually need a loop which feeds into functions a different list of rows on each loop?